The Hilbert cube cannot be embedded in some Euclidean space $\mathbb R^n$
The Hilbert cube $X=[0,1]^\mathbb N$ with the product topology cannot be embedded in some Euclidean space $\mathbb R^n$ for some finite $n$.
What would be a simple way to show this?
I am particularly interested in approaches that don't make explicit use of theorems from dimension theory.
Do these approaches also apply to more general classes of spaces?

(Added later) Context: The result seems intuitively clear.  $(0,1)^n$ is homeomorphic to $\mathbb R^n$, which is $n$-dimensional.  So $(0,1)^\mathbb N$ and $[0,1]^\mathbb N$ should be infinite dimensional, and thus not be embeddable into a finite-dimensional $\mathbb R^n$.
But that's a lot of hand-waving.  It would be nice to see an argument that does not use so much dimension theory.
Furthermore, that will allow to give a justification for the property in pi-base: https://topology.pi-base.org/spaces/S000032/properties/P000184.

Could you add more details to your post? As it is currently written, there is not much context in it

context added now

It can be proven as a consequence of the invariance of domain theorem:
Since every Euclidean space (obviously homeomorphic to $(0,1)^n$) can be embedded into a Hilbert cube, an embedding of the Hilbert cube into some $\mathbb R^m$ would provide a continuous injection $f$ of $\mathbb R^{m+1}$ into $\mathbb R^m$.  Composing $f$ with the standard inclusion of $\mathbb R^m$ into $\mathbb R^{m+1}$ would give a continuous injection $f$ from $\mathbb R^{m+1}$ to itself, but with an image with empty interior in $\mathbb R^{m+1}$.  This would contradict invariance of domain.

So, your argument also proves in general that if a space contains subspaces homeomorphic to Euclidean space $\mathbb R^n$ for arbitrarily large $n$, it cannot itself be embedded into a fixed $\mathbb R^m$.  Right?

Yes. This is the only property of $[0,1]^\omega$ we need here.

Let $\text{ind}$ be small inductive dimension, $\text{Ind}$ large inductive dimension and $\dim$ Lebesgue covering dimension. Here $n\in\mathbb{N}$ is a natural number.
Proposition 1. Suppose $X$ is a separable metrizable space. Then $\text{ind}(X) = \text{Ind}(X) = \dim(X)$.
Proposition 2. Suppose $X\subseteq Y$, then $\text{ind}(X)\leq \text{ind}(Y)$.
Proposition 3. $\dim \mathbb{R}^n = \dim [0, 1]^n = n$
Proposition 4. If $X$ is a separable metrizable space and $\dim(X)\leq n$ then $X$ embeds into $\mathbb{R}^{2n+1}$.
This can be found in e.g. Theory of dimensions: Finite and infinite by Engelking or in Dimension theory by Charalambous.
Definition. Say that a separable metrizable space $X$ is finite-dimensional if $\dim(X) < \infty$.
It follows from propositions 2, 3 and 4 that:
Theorem. $X$ can be embedded into $\mathbb{R}^n$ for some $n$ if and only if $X$ is a finite-dimensional separable metrizable space.
Since the Hilbert cube contains $[0, 1]^n$ for each $n$ as a subspace, it follows from proposition 2 that $\dim [0, 1]^\omega = \infty$, and so it cannot embed into $\mathbb{R}^n$ for any $n$.
